# How to create own application installer for Linux?

Tags: software-installation, java, gui

I would like to develop a sefl-made application graphical installer in Java. But I not found is quite a good tutorial for this.

I saw izPack installer creator, but for this documentation is quite incomplete.

Therefore, I consider it is currently the best option when the installer I create myself, but I do not know how this can be implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally people do not use graphical install wizards in GNU/Linux environments. Either they will install through the command line or through a graphical package manager such as Synaptic.

I'm afraid there's not much call for what you are trying to achieve, hence the lack of tutorials. I would recommend you look at creating `debs`, `rpms` and `tarballs` for package installation as opposed to a graphical install wizard.

Here's a couple of links to get you started:

- [RPM](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-build.html)
- [deb](https://www.howtoforge.com/howto_linux_debian_deb_checkinstall)
- [tarballs](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/t/tarball.htm) and [makefiles](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/)